# Passing information from one port to onther in Java

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I am creating a simple java program that creates two threads when it starts, each of these thread creates a server that listen to different port(ie port 5500, 5100), those servers each have clients, now i want the servers to be able to pass information from their client to each other. How do i do that. this is the code i have for the servers

```
class SocketSeverBrooker extends Thread{
    int portNumber = 5500;
    ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    int clientID = 10000;


    public void run(){

        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);


            while(true){
                try{
                    // i am accepting acconection from a client
                    Socket clientsocket = serverSocket.accept();
                    new Thread(new BrokerRunnable(clientsocket)).start();
                    System.out.println("a broker has connected with id "+ clientID);
                    clientID++;
                }catch(IOException e){
                    System.out.println("client could not connect");
                }

            }

        }catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println("could not create a connection");
        }

    }
}

class BrokerRunnable implements Runnable{

  protected Socket clientSocket;


    public BrokerRunnable(Socket clientSocket) {
        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
    }

    public void run() {
        // create two way communication
       // this is used to get input from the connected client clientSocket.getInputStream()

        // new BufferedReader();

        try{

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(),true);// write the sever
            String arg1;
            arg1 = in.readLine();
            System.out.println( arg1);
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            String msgToBrokker = scanner.nextLine();
            out.println(msgToBrokker);


        }catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("could not read");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. The way you create a client connection doesn't change just because there is a thread also listening as a server.

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to ask a question using a comment. Hence writing here. Sorry.

What i understood from the question, Please correct me if this is not the case.

1. We have multiple servers (S) and each may have multiple clients (C) too.
   S1 -> S1C1, S1C2, ...., S1Cn
   S2 -> S2C1, S2C2, ...., S2Cn
   ......
   Sm -> SmC1, SmC2, ...., SmCn
2. Servers to share information with other servers that can be passed to clients.

If above understanding is correct, then you should have a common object (like a list, map) which can be shared by all the Servers. This object will store the information from all the servers. You will need to put a logic how will you which information to read by a server (for ex. S1 shouldn't read the information added by itself).

Hope this helps.